# Difference between model(x) and model.predict(x) in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

What is the difference between using `model(x)` and `model.predict(x)` for predicting the outcome of a model in Keras?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Keras with tensorflow backend was using underlying tensorflow objects, but mostly was providing high level outputs which could be understood outside the tensorflow environment (as an example it could output numpy arrays or python lists).
 Today given a model in tensorflow 2.0 (built using the keras library),

```
out_np = model.predict(x)
```

provides a numpy array which can, as an example, be printed with `print(out_np)`.

 On the other hand,

```
out_tf = model(x)
```

results into a tensorflow object, wich can be converted to a numpy array with `.numpy()`

 The two results are equivalent, as an example, we have that the following is True,

```
out_np.max() == out_tf.numpy().max()
```

The format may be different, but the meaning of `model(x)` and `model.predict(x)` is the same: 
 given an input x, it is the value of the output nodes of a network characterized by its structure, weights and biases.

Answer (score 0):

They are not exactly the same thing.
From [Chollet's Deep Learning with Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617294438):

> .... This means that `predict()` calls can scale to very large arrays. Meanwhile, `model(x)` happens in-memory and doesn’t scale. On the other hand, `predict()` is not differentiable: you cannot retrieve its gradient if you call it in a GradientTape scope.
> You should use `model(x)` when you need to retrieve the gradients of the model call, and you should use `predict()` if you just need the output value. In other words, always use `predict()` unless you’re in the middle of writing a low-level gradient descent loop (as we are now).